# vimeo api wmode=window?

Tags: performance, vimeo-api

Is there any way to set `wmode="window"` for vimeo player?

`wmode="opaque"` (as default for vimeo player) causes 50% cpu usage on my site.

There was the same problem with another players and `wmode="window"` solves problem.